# How Can I see my Diagnostics Trace of my Azure Worker Role?

Tags: .net, logging, azure, trace, diagnostics

I have a doubt with  Azure Trace Logs.
I have a Worker Role and I want to log certain events,

When we deploy the application locally we can read the Trace using Cerebrata Cerebrata Cloud Storage.
But when we deploy to staying or production we can't. We are using the same Storage accounts.

Worker Code:

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
        diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
        diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        DiagnosticMonitor diagnosticMonitor = DiagnosticMonitor.Start(cloudStorageAccount, diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
        return base.OnStart();
    }

     public override void Run()
    {
        // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        Trace.WriteLine("UpdateWorker entry point called", "Information");

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

App.config

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <configuration>
        <system.diagnostics>
          <trace>
            <listeners>
              <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                  name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
              </add>
            </listeners>
          </trace>
        </system.diagnostics>
      </configuration>
```

Where should we look? Is something wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Try out DbgView.exe utility http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Comment: Everything looks about right.  Are you sure you changed the connection string to something starting with https and not "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

Comment: There's a useful MSDN article about Azure logging here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is on the line with

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
```

You are referencing the local development storage on your computer, which will not be available when running in the cloud. Use a proper connection string to Azure Storage and use that for writing the logs to.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to add the Azure Storage connection string 
“ServiceConfiguration.cscfg” file

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Storage Account Name>;AccountKey=<Storage Account Key>" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```